# Spark 2.0: A named function inside mapGroups for sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset cause java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: apache-spark-sql, scala-collections, apache-spark-2.0

Anonymous function work fine.

For following code set up the problem:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("demo").getOrCreate()
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

case class DemoRow(keyId: Int, evenOddId: Int)
case class EvenOddCountRow(keyId: Int, oddCnt: Int, evenCnt: Int)

val demoDS = sc.parallelize(Seq(DemoRow(1, 1),
                                DemoRow(1, 2),
                                DemoRow(1, 3), 
                                DemoRow(2, 1),
                                DemoRow(2, 2))).toDS()
```

Showing the `demoDS.show()`:

```
+-----+---------+
|keyId|evenOddId|
+-----+---------+
|    1|        1|
|    1|        2|
|    1|        3|
|    2|        1|
|    2|        2|
+-----+---------+
```

Using the Anonymous function `id => id % 2 == 1` inside `mapGroups()` works fine:

```
val demoGroup = demoDS.groupByKey(_.keyId).mapGroups((key, iter) => {
  val evenOddIds = iter.map(_.evenOddId).toList
  val (oddIds, evenIds) = evenOddIds.partition(id => id % 2 == 1)
  EvenOddCountRow(key, oddIds.size, evenIds.size)
})
```

The result of `demoGroup.show()` is what we expected:

```
+-----+------+-------+
|keyId|oddCnt|evenCnt|
+-----+------+-------+
|    1|     2|      1|
|    2|     1|      1|
+-----+------+-------+
```

Now if I define the `isOdd` function, and put it into the function inside `mapGroups()` like below, it will raise Exception:

```
def isOdd(id: Int) = id % 2 == 1

val demoGroup = demoDS.groupByKey(_.keyId).mapGroups((key, iter) => {
  val evenOddIds = iter.map(_.evenOddId).toList
  val (oddIds, evenIds) = evenOddIds.partition(isOdd)
  EvenOddCountRow(key, oddIds.size, evenIds.size)
})
```

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1

I tried different ways of define the `isOdd` function try to make it serializable:

```
val isOdd = (id: Int) => id % 2 == 1 // does not work

case object isOdd extends Function[Int, Boolean] with Serializable {
  def apply(id: Int) = id % 2 == 1
} // still does not work
```

Did I miss any thing or anything wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
object Utils {
  def isOdd(id: Int) = id % 2 == 1
}
```

And then use:

```
evenOddIds.partition(Utils.isOdd)
```

Comment: Strange. After restart the spark-shell, not only your solution work, my previous solutions works too. ...